# Hide the scroll bar in Phonegap application

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

[image]

Hi
I am working on a phonegap app. here is the code for the scrollable area

```
<div id = "contentoutter" style ="width:'+winwidth+'px;height:'+screendummy+';float:left;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;margin-top:'+height50+'px;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;position:relative;">
```

this code is in javascript and this div is appended to body. there appears a right vertical bar which i am unable to get rid off. how do i get rid off it?

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 7):

Use [-webkit-scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) in your `CSS` file. It will hide all scrollbars across the app.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

If you want to hide the scrollbars for a specific element then:

```
#your_element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: This answer is a good waste of. Apparently not a mobile developer.

Comment: This is an answer coming from a phonegap application of mine and it works as expected

Comment: So you are confirming what I am saying.